# Why Interfaces can not have constructor but abstract classes have constructor

Tags: oop, constructor, interface, abstract-class

We all know that we can not create the object of both interface and abstract class.But why we are allowed to have constructor in abstract class but not in interface? object of both can not be created.I want very straight forward answer not very complex answer.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces (at least in .NET and Java, for example) are meant to serve exclusively as what they are named for - to guarantee a certain interface (i.e. set of (public) members) in all implementing classes.

Interfaces are not supposed to have a state, and they are not even supposed to define something like an initial state. Without an initial state, nothing reasonable would be left for a constructor of an interface to be done.

Answer (score 1):

An interface is just a set of member signatures that must be fulfilled by an implementation. Why you can't define constructors? **Because constructors are an implementation detail**.

Let's say that when you want to hire someone you're not focused on *who's the candidate* but *what can do the candidate* (this is a simplification). Does your candidate own desired tech background? Can your candidate do teamwork? From OOP's point of view, you know what a candidate must fulfill to work with you. Therefore, I don't care about a candidate's mother and when/how candidate was born: I care about what properties and behaviors are acceptable for me **today**. So you would define an interface like `CanWorkOnMyCompany` for that matter.

In the other hand, an abstract class is a regular class on which some members are signatures and a derived class must provide an implementation to them. That is, you can't instantiate an abstract class because it's not fully implemented.

Probably you could argue that an abstract class can provide no abstract member, but it's not their purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are for initializing the state of a new instance.

Abstract classes can define state and can have constructors to initialize it.

Interfaces can't define any state and so have no need for constructors.

Comment: Well, I think that's not the entire reason (see e.g. [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41741609/1430156)), as interfaces *could* initialize the properties they declare to some initial state, even though arguably they do not store ("have") that state themselves.

Comment: Do you mean the constructor of an interface could call a setter or any other method defined by the interface? Calling abstract/virtual/overridable methods from constructors is usually considered a severe code smell. I would argue that is why interfaces can't have constructors in the first place.

Comment: Calling overrideable methods from constructors has its place when those methods do not rely on the object state (but e.g. provide some class-specific information), especially in languages that lack overrideable static members, as C# does. I agree calling order of interface constructors vs. class constructors is not obvious and could be a concern, though.

Comment: That wouldn't really be different from multiple inheritence.

Comment: What interfaces are meant for or what their purpose is is mostly identical to abstract classes, especially when they only have abstract/virtual methods. Then the only distinction is state.